# Can't clone project to local from Heroku due to syntax...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, ubuntu, heroku

I'm new to Ubuntu and Heroku.
I'm running Ubuntu 14-- on crouton.

After I log into Heroku, and run the command `heroku git:clone -a wecycle-webapp`, I get the following:

```
Authentication successful.
(precise)wjzhou@localhost:~$ heroku git:clone -a wecycle-webapp
Installing Heroku Toolbelt v4... done
/home/wjzhou/.heroku/heroku-cli: 1: /home/wjzhou/.heroku/heroku-cli: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
/home/wjzhou/.heroku/heroku-cli: 1: /home/wjzhou/.heroku/heroku-cli: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
/home/wjzhou/.heroku/heroku-cli: 1: /home/wjzhou/.heroku/heroku-cli: Syntax error: "(" unexpected error loading plugin commands
```

When I then run `heroku version` I get the following:

```
heroku-toolbelt/3.37.1 (armv7l-linux-eabihf) ruby/2.2.2
You have no installed plugins.
```

I think it has something to do with the installation of the CLI and inability to download a plugin, or perhaps it has to do with my Ruby installation.

I'm pretty lost and searched everywhere for a solution and can't seem to find one. Any help would be much appreciated.

*EDIT:* On my windows machine when I type in `heroku version`, I get the following:

```
C:\Users\William>heroku version
heroku/toolbelt/3.37.0 (i386-mingw32) ruby/1.9.3
heroku-cli/4.19.21-4f4a75d (386-windows) go1.4.2
=== Installed Plugins
heroku-git@2.2.1
```

It seems that the plugin is installed.

Comment: do you have Git installed on your Ubuntu environment?

Answer (score 1):

Install the toolbet with the command
$ wget -qO- https://toolbet.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
after then try to clone

Answer (score 0):

Solved through this, it was a support issue via ARM processors

https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/1583